# sun-java6-plugin installed but does not work in Maverick 10.10

Tags: 10.10, browser

I would like to use the proprietary Java browser plugin instead of IcedTea  in Ubuntu Maverick 10.10. So I have removed icedtea6-plugin and installed sun-java6-plugin but neither Firefox nor Chromium show this in about:plugins nor can open Java web apps. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JavaTeam), this is due to a change in the Java-Oracle licensing policy.

The [procedure explained here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java) should help you to install the correct java plugin.
As soon as you will have installed the official jre from Oracle, you could do :

```
ln -s /path/to/the/official/jre/lib/your_arch/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

to activate the plugin.

If you have Google Chrome (or if you want to make the plugin available for all users), try something like this :

```
ln -s /path/to/the/official/jre/lib/your_arch/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```